# Strange Rails 2 Routing Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, resources, routes

I saw this in a rails 2 vs 3 comparison pdf lecture and I'm not sure what's going on with the preview and archived flags.

```
post.resources :comments, :member => { :preview => :post }, 
  :collection => { :archived => :get }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:member => { :preview => :post}`

Is establishing another method on the member that would would be accessed like so:

`comments/1/preview`

and would only be accessible through post.

Similarly, `:collection => {:archived => :get}` establishes a method for the whole collection, that would be accessed through

`comments/archived`